# Column 0 of table 'sitemanager.b_agent' cannot be converted from type 'bigint' to type 'int(18)'

Tags: mysql

I have a Percona MySQL server with 1 master & 1 slave I'm having this kind of issue on my slave part

```
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 
                  Master_User: 
                  Master_Port: 
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.069991
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 306526721
               Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.000618
                Relay_Log_Pos: 11406
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.069991
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 1677
                   Last_Error: Column 0 of table 'sitemanager.b_agent' cannot be converted from type 'bigint' to type 'int(18)'
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 180839625
              Relay_Log_Space: 125698703
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: /var/lib/mysql/ca.pem
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert: /var/lib/mysql/server.crt
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key: /var/lib/mysql/server.key
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1677
               Last_SQL_Error: Column 0 of table 'sitemanager.b_agent' cannot be converted from type 'bigint' to type 'int(18)'
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: 07c9e21b-52fe-11ea-ad07-005056bd1b5a
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State:
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 231031 18:05:17
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> ERROR:
> No query specified

Comment: Sounds like the table `b_agent` on the replica has a different data type than its source. Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE sitemanager.b_agent` on the source and the replica using a query tool? What does the first column (i.e. column 0) look like?

Comment: Perhaps `BIGINT SIGNED` vs `BIGINT UNSIGNED`?